# Erro ao inserir dados no JPA

Tags: java, jpa

```java
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
// pode usar para alterar o nome da tabela la no banco
//@Table(name = "")
public class Usuario {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    @Column(name= "login_usu")
    private String login;
    private String senha;

    public void mostrar() {
        System.out.printf("Id: %-5d Login: %-30s Senha: %-20s \n", id, login, senha);
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getLogin() {
        return login;
    }

    public void setLogin(String login) {
        this.login = login;
    }

    public String getSenha() {
        return senha;
    }

    public void setSenha(String senha) {
        this.senha = senha;
    }

}
```

```java
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;

public class ConnectionFactory {

    private static EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("aula09");
    public static EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return emf.createEntityManager();
    }

}
```

```java
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;

public class Principal {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Usuario u = new Usuario();
        u.setLogin("aaaaaaa@gmail.com");
        u.setSenha("senha123");

        EntityManager em = ConnectionFactory.getEntityManager();
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        em.persist(u);
        em.getTransaction();
        em.close();

    }
}
```

Quando mando rodar, tudo é criado porém não são inseridas as informações no banco de dados.

Comment: O seu campo senha não tem anotação.

Comment: Editei a sua pergunta porque você está usando JPA, e não JDBC diretamente. Além disso, tirei a tag [sql] porque você não está tendo problema com `SELECT`s, `INSERT`s, `UPDATE`s e `DELETE`s - você não está utilizando-os diretamente.

Answer (score 2):

Partindo do princípio que as suas configurações no `persistence.xml` estão corretas, faça o seguinte:

1. "Anote" seu atributo `senha` com `@Column(name="NOME_DA_COLUNA")`
2. Na linha em seguida do método `persist(u)`, chame o método `commit()` com: `em.getTransaction().commit();`

No final ficará assim (resumidamente):

```
@Entity
public class Usuario {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Column(name= "login_usu")
    private String login;

    @Column(name="NOME_DA_COLUNA")
    private String senha;

    //getters e setters

}
```

---

```
public class Principal {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Usuario u = new Usuario();
        u.setLogin("aaaaaaa@gmail.com");
        u.setSenha("senha123");

        EntityManager em = ConnectionFactory.getEntityManager();
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        em.persist(u);
        em.getTransaction().commit();
        em.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: maaaano, tu é muito fera. Fiquei mt tempo e nao vi. vlw de mais manin vlw d++++

Comment: @user66600 Se esta resposta solucionou o seu problema e não resta mais nenhum questionamento ou dúvida, marque-a como aceita/correta ao clicar no ✅ aqui ao lado. Com isso a sua pergunta é marcada como resolvida/solucionada.

Comment: nao estou achando esse lugar para falar que resolveu

Comment: @user66600 tem um sinal de check (em cinza) logo abaixo dos votos da resposta, se não me engano

Comment: @user66600 por favor, marque a resposta como solução.. Se ficar sem solução toda hora alguém vai entrar aqui e depois de ler tudo vai ver que o problema já foi resolvido